# How to merge two SQL server database into one with foreign key relationships and then migrate that DB to Postgres with all foreign key relation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, data-migration

I have two SQL server databases that have many tables with foreign key relationships between them.
I need to combine these two SQL server databases into one (preserving foreign key relationships) and then migrate that combined single database to Postgres. I need to preserve all the foreign key relationships.

My end goal is to have one Postgres DB with all the foreign key constraints. If migrating the two SQL server DB to two Postgres DB and then combining the two Postgres DBs into one Postgres is better, that also will work.

What is the best way to do this?